# Single word for generic times of day

Tags: meaning

Is there a single word that refers to the type of word that the words dawn, morning, afternoon, evening, ect are?

I'm looking for something more specific than 'time.'

Comment: This gets asked a lot.  There is no good answer other than "[*time of day*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97129/what-is-the-category-name-to-describe-day-night-or-dusk)" or the slightly more awkward/obscure but technical "[*daypart*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37670/what-to-call-the-collective-parts-of-a-day?rq=1)". The way StackExchange works, your question is going to be marked as a duplicate of one of those two, so consider all the answers under those questions.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that question when I searched. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yeah, SE is *really* hard to search for dupes. I even *knew* those questions existed and still had to use Google to find them.

Comment: I wish there was a way to append different phrasings to questions when there are duplicates for SEO, but that's a conversation for Meta I suppose.